# backbone.js escaping html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

im pulling html from my database to display on my page using backbone.js

the data is stored like this

<p>   TEST</p>  <p>TEST 1</p>  <p>TEST 2</p>

in my page when using underscore.js

> pp<%= title  %>
>
> <%= mainContent %>
>
> ```
>     </div>            </div>      </script>
>
>   <!-- sample template for pagination UI -->      <script
> ```
>
> type="text/html" id="tmpServerPagination">
>
> ```
>               <% if (currentPage < totalPages) { %>
>                   <a href="#" class="btn long servernext">Show More</a>
>               <% } %>
>
>         </div>
>     </script>
> ```

it renders

TEST

TEST 1

TEST 2

Where i want it to read the tags and apply the formating   to the page

TEST
TEST 1
TEST 2

this is my view

> ( function ( views ){
>
> views.ResultView = Backbone.View.extend({
>         tagName: 'li',
>                 template: _.template($('#resultItemTemplate').html()),
>                 initialize: function() {            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);           this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
>         },
>
> ```
>   render : function () {
>       this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));          return this;
>   }   });
> ```
>
> })(app.views);

Comment: want to remove html tags from the string?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to display the paragraphs inline, then you could use:

`p {
  display: inline-block;
}`

You'll probably want to namespace this (e.g. `.pagination p`) so that it doesn't affect all the paragraphs on the page.